# factory_boy UserFactory: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, nose, factory-boy

I'm trying to create a `UserFactory`, and I get this error when running `./manage.py test`:

```
OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

This is what my `factories.py` file looks like:

```
import factory
import django.contrib.auth.models as auth_models
from wacep.weatherroulette.models import (
    GameState, Puzzle
)


class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "user_%d" % n)


class PuzzleFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Puzzle

    display_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Test Puzzle {0}'.format(n))
    description = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Description {0}'.format(n))


class GameStateFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = GameState

    user = UserFactory()
    current_inventory = 300
```

Anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh.. Inheriting from `factory.Factory` instead of `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory` seems to fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the error occurs because `django.contrib.auth` is not part of your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

The error you see happens when `factory_boy` tries to create a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and doesn't find the related table in the database.

That table should have been automatically created at the beginning of the test by Django's test runner ; the fact that it wasn't created means that you didn't add `django.contrib.auth` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I did have `django.contrib.auth` in my `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` though -- that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I actually got to this question because I had the same problem myself, and after a little research I think I know what the issue is. As you've probably guessed, it has to do with this line:

```
user = UserFactory()
```

What you're actually doing here will try to create the User object without properly using the Django ORM. As a sidenote: I haven't entirely parsed what goes wrong here -- either it tries to create a User object during the import before the test database is set up, or it doesn't actually communicate with the appropriate database. The upshot at least is that it needs a little bit of Django magic to create your object. And factory_boy provides that magic.

Changing this line to:

```
user = UserFactory.create()
```

ought to fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a late answer, but I have suffered this issue today and want to share my solution.

Using django, my develop setting `settings.local` uses Postgresql but the test setting `settings.test` uses sqlite3. Running the test under `settings.test` resulted in `no such table` error, as below.

```
$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.test python manage.py test
OperationalError: no such table: ...
```

This seems because the sqlite3 database has no schema as I have never used sqlite3 for developing. So I `migrate` for sqlite

```
$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.test python manage.py migrate
# ... migration running for sqlite3 ...
```

As the migration finished, I could run the tests with the sqlite3 test database as intended.